# Connect to Foursquare app in developer mode

Tags: foursquare

Following the advice of a fellow Stack Overflow user (on a previous question which I asked: [Lastest Foursquare check-in on map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015293/lastest-foursquare-checkin-on-map)) I have written a PHP-based Foursquare app which uses the Push API to show my latest checkin on a map which I can then embed into my blog.

Obviously I would like to keep this app private, so that it only shows my latest checkins. I figured the best way would be to keep the app in Developer Mode, but it seems that I can't connect to the app myself (i.e. using the same account as I used to create the app) in this mode. This also means that I can't even test the app is working properly, as I can't send test push messages from my own account when I checkin to certain locations. Is there a way around this issue? Alternatively, what other options are available for keeping the app private?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you create the app in "Developer mode", lookup the `Client ID` and manually navigate to:

`https://foursquare.com/app/<CLIENT_ID>`